# Multiply every element of an array by the same scalar in zsh

Tags: arrays, shell, zsh, integer-arithmetic

I would like to multiply every element in an array in zsh by the same scalar. I would be able to do this very easily in Python, but have looked in many places and cannot figure out how to do it in a zsh script.

I would like to write code like

```
#!/bin/zsh
mean=(1 2 2 1 -1 -2 -2 -1)
echo $((2 * $mean))
```

But when I try to do this I get the error message

```
bad math expression: operator expected at `2 2 1 -1 -...'
```

Any and all help would be appreciated. I can't seem to find anything online that is even remotely close to what I'm trying to figure out how to do.

Comment: There is no `map` function in zsh, as you are used to it from Python. You have to do it the old-fashioned way, by looping over the array.

Answer (score 1):

You have to iterate over the elements of the array and multiply each one:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env zsh
typeset -a mean=(1 2 2 1 -1 -2 -2 -1)
for n in "${mean[@]}"; do
    print $((2 * n))
done
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some hacky ways to implement a `map()`:

```
$ set -o extendedglob
$ a=(1 2 2 1 -1 -2 -2 -1)
$ print ${a//(#m)*/$((MATCH * 2))}
2 4 4 2 -2 -4 -4 -2
```

But a loop is probably the easiest:

```
$ b=(); for i ($a) b+=$((i*2)); print $b
2 4 4 2 -2 -4 -4 -2
```